# How do I go to another SwiftUI view programmatically using Button(action:{}) {} instead of a NavigationLink or NavigationView?

Tags: macos, button, swiftui

I am trying to programmatically change views in my MacOS application. I am not allowed to use `NavigationLink` or `NavigationView` or similar. The code to switch must be in the `action: {}` of a `Button`, because this way I know that I can quickly switch from the code, even if it is not in button format. How can I do this?

Button in `ContentView.swift`:

```
Button(action: {
    // What goes here? Settings() did not work
}) {
    Text("Settings")
}.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
```

`Settings.swift`:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Settings: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, world!")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, you need `3 views` here to achieve this functionality, 
Main `ContentView` to switch views (HomeView & SettingView).

Here `HomeView` contains `Setting button` and has one `@Binding` variable to handle button click on `ContentView`.

So, whenever you click on `Setting` button on `HomeView` it will toggle value of 
`settingView` variable of `ContentView` and switch view according to it's value.

try below code.

**ContentView :**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var settingView = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if self.settingView {
                Settings()
            } else {
              HomeView(buttonClick: $settingView)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**HomeView :**

```
struct HomeView: View {
        @Binding var buttonClick: Bool

        var body: some View {
            VStack {
                Button(action: {
                    withAnimation {
                        self.buttonClick.toggle()
                    }
                }) {
                    Text("Settings")
                }.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure I need all that?

Comment: As i have implemented this functionality in iOS. I needed all these. So you can also try, if it can solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example:

In the `action` block of the button you can not put a `view`. But you can toggle a `bool`, which is a `@State` variable, which updates the `view` and will show a different view when `true`. I added an animation with `.transition()`, but you need to put `withAnimation` around the change of the `@State` variable to make it work.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showView = false

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            ZStack {
                if self.showView {
                    VStack {
                        Text("Settings View")
                        Button(action: {
                            withAnimation {
                                self.showView.toggle()
                            }
                        }, label: {
                            Text("Back")
                        })
                    }
                    .frame(width: proxy.size.width, height: proxy.size.height)
                    .background(Color.red)
                    .transition(.move(edge: .trailing))
                } else {
                    VStack {
                        Text("Home View")
                        Button(action: {
                            withAnimation {
                                self.showView.toggle()
                            }
                        }, label: {
                            Text("Settings")
                        })
                    }
                    .frame(width: proxy.size.width, height: proxy.size.height)
                    .background(Color.green)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

If you click start on the first view, it navigates you to the next view. You can edit the first view to fit your view requirements

**GloryHUbApp.swift**

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct GloryHubApp: App {
@State var currentStage = "OnboardingView"
var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
            if(self.currentStage == "OnboardingView"){
                StartButtonView(currentStage: $currentStage)
            } else if(self.currentStage == "LoginView"){
                NextView()
            }
    }
  }
}
```

**ButtonView.swift**

```
import SwiftUI
struct StartButtonView: View {
// MARK: - PROPERTIES
@Binding var currentStage: String
// MARK: - BODY
var body: some View {
    Button(action: {
        //appStage = "LoginView"
        self.currentStage = "LoginView"
    }) {
        HStack (spacing: 8) {
            Text("START")
        }
    } //: BUTTO
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import SwiftUI

struct StartButtonView: View {

    @State private var isActive = false

    var body: some View {

    Button(action: {
       isActive = true
    }, label: { 
       Text("START")
    })

    NavigationLink(destination: Settings(), isActive: $isActive) { }
}
```